# Enable HTTP request/response logging in Spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to check the details of the HTTP request/response. I notice that I can see the log by setting to true `enableLoggingRequestDetails` in `HttpWebHandlerAdapter`. I don't understand what the correct configuration is for getting the details.

I obtain this:

```
org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter                     : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': form data and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
```

Comment: You can use Filter to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
    }
}
```